# How to make makefile find depends file in the same directory

Tags: makefile

Some linux properties were changed in the recent linux update, so that now a previously functioning Makefile can't find a depends file in the same directory from which I run the make command.

The error I get is:
*Makefile:11: depends: No such file or directory*

Although the file is in the directory.

The makefile code is:

```
LIB_NAME=libfuncs

include ../makevars
CFILES=src/strlcpy.c src/strlcat.c
OBJS=$(CFILES:.c=.o)
CFLAGS+=-Iinc/ -static


$(LIB_NAME): $(OBJS)
    ar rcs ../out/$(LIB_NAME).a $(OBJS)
include depends
depends:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $(CFILES) > depends
clean:
    rm -f *.o src/*.o depends ../out/$(LIB_NAME).a
```

I've tried putting the absolute directory of depends in both "include" and 
"$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $(CFILES) > $(current_dir)/depends", using both:

current_dir = $(shell pwd) 
and
current_dir = $(notdir $(shell pwd))

The error remains. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: The include should be told to ignore errors: `-include depends`, if the makefile was failing because `depends` had been deleted then that's all it should take, if not then you'll need to show how you're invoking make.

Comment: If, as you say, the file `depends` is present in the working directory, you can remove most of the code in this makefile and still reproduce the error. Then you can try some other experiments to clinch it, such as `$(info $(shell cat depends))`